# Needs some Angular Design suggestion for async calls

Tags: javascript, angular

I need an help to design a way to allow my Angular Component to subscribe a js wrapper function.

In the image below, you can see a flowchart.

Im creating an Angular Frontent that have to dialogate with a pre-existing system I cannot touch so much.

This system manages an OpenLayer Map and has a JS wrapper around it. We can operate on map calling this wrapper that has function like "centerMap" , "refreshMap" etc...

When the MapManager.js - thats has the OpenLayer object - get some request from its wrapper, calls a PHP server thats read a PostGIS DB and gives back the elements to be draw.

[image]

To dialogate with this system, I've created another wrapper inside Angular to use it inside any components. I need my own wrapper because original one is written in plain JS and I need a TS library.

This system works perfectly. Angular is able to operate on Map. Unfortunally, AngularWrapper is a sync call from AngularComponent but its not from MapManager.js prospective because its has to make an async call to PHP server so when my wrapper has ended the call, the map is still processing data.

Example:

I need to call a Filter Resources and then center the Map to the first one found. I need to know if no resources has been found with filters.

**internalwrapper.ts**

```
function filterResources(filters)
{
    original_wrapper.send("filter",filters);        
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var resources = original_wrapper.send("getCurrentElements",{});
        var first_one = array_shift(resources);
        original_wrapper.send("centerMap",{ "lat" : first_one.lat, "lon" : first_one.lon" });
        }
    },1000)   
}
```

As you can see, I had to put a TimeOut to wait until the async call of server has ended. Than I can call getCurrentElements to get the results of filter call, taking the first one of then and then call again the original_wrapper to center the OpenLayer Map to the resources.

Without the timeout, the getCurrentElements return the elements "before" the call (old ones).
The Timeout is a trick that resolve the CENTERMAP problem but AngularComponents is still unaware of what its happening and has no vision of the results of its filter.

In Angular components, I call the filter simply importing the function:

**components.ts**

```
import { filterResources } from '....assets/map/internalwrapper'; 

[...]

applyFilter()
{
    var params = {};
    [...]
    filterResources(params);
}
```

Is there a way to create some sort of Observable service to allow the Angular Component to know whats is happening (and maybe opening a SnackBar with some info)? 
In my current situation, AngularComponents is unaware. The operator can see some changes on the Map but not AngularFrontend.

Comment: what is that mysterious `send()` method does it return anything ? how does it invoke stuff ? http calls ? also you are aware that every valid `.js` file is a valid `.ts` file right ?

Comment: "send" method doesn't return anythings. Its simply call the map-object provided by mapmanager.js with a sync call. For example: `setMapCenter(lon, lat) {
  this.mapobject.applyRemote("SetCenter", arguments);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem simply asking for "callback pattern" to the MapManager developers.
Javascirpt doesn't lost reference so I create a function on AngularComponent to manage the results passed to my wrapper thats is received by other wrapper and then passet to MapManager. When the mapmanager ends the Ajax Call, call any callback received.

I was lucky the function reference is not lost during then inner calls.